# Kernel reset in Python after running SVD

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning, svd

I am trying to do SVD of a (800k x 200k) Numpy array in Python. Probably due to intense computation, the kernel dies out everytime i try. It also happens when I try to convert the original matrix into a sparse matrix.

Is there a way i can forcefully keep the kernel active and prevent it from dying each time?

Comment: So you have a 1.2TB array?  I am surprised you can even load it in Numpy, let alone do anything with it.  Or are your numbers off a little?  Or are you using some form of clustering?

Comment: urm.shape  >> (889167, 253059). I guess that's the order.  I created my own matrix decomposition function and it's been running for some time without failing. Im wondering what causes a kernal to die.